# Plotting a pencil of lines

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a pencil of lines between line1 and line2 using a formula (alfa*(ax+by+c)+beta*(a1x+b1y+c1)), but it doesn't show me anything.

```
    line1 = {2, -3, 4};
    line2 = {1, 2, -20};
    pp = {x, y, 1};
    ContourPlot[{line1.pp == 0, line2.pp == 0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
    ContourPlot[{α*(line1.pp) + β*(line2.pp) == 0}, {α, 1, 10}, {β, 1, 10}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you want `α, β` to range over some (finite number) of values between `1` and `10`.  Use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) to generate the equations.  These needed to be flattened into a plain list, since the table will be a two-dimensional array.  (We also need `Evaluate` since `ContourPlot` would otherwise hold the code unevaluated and think there was just one formula to plot.)

```
line1 = {2, -3, 4};
line2 = {1, 2, -20};
pp = {x, y, 1};

ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Flatten@
   Table[{α*(line1.pp) + β*(line2.pp) == 0}, {α, 
     1, 10}, {β, 1, 10}], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nicely done.  Note that the original code was effectively asking Mathematica to plot the contour `α*(line1.pp) + β*(line2.pp) == 0` with `α` on the horizontal axis and `β` on the vertical axis, which left `x` and `y` unspecified and resulted in a blank output.

Comment: Is this known as "a pencil of lines" -- never heard of that before.  +1 of course.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thank you. I probably should have noted the error in the original code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, [pencil](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pencil.html) is a somewhat oldish term, but still in use in [algebraic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_system_of_divisors), usually denoting a one-dimensional family. Not sure why the name "pencil."